# CUDA is it possible to have out-of-bound access that results in no error?

Tags: c++, cuda, indexoutofboundsexception, undefined-behavior

So I've met a very strange behavior in CUDA.

I have multiple arrays on GPU, let's say one is `float a[100];`

I have a function that looks like the following:

```
float access(int i) {
    if (i >= 100) printf("i is out of bound\n");
    if (i+blockDim.x >= 100) printf("i+blockDim.x is out of bound\n");
    return a[i] + a[i + blockDim.x];
}
```

During execution the second statement is printed multiple times. However, even if I use `cudaGetLastError()` everywhere, the function still does not catch the bug!

The program never crashes. `nvprof` also doesn't show any error.

My best guess is something like the following:

```
float a[100]; // byte 0, 4, 8, ..., 396
...
float z[100]; // byte 400, 404, 408, ...
```

Which means when I access `a[100]`, I'm actually accessing `z[0]`, so it doesn't crash.

Are there any other possible reason for this?

Edit: in my actual programs the out-of-bound access is very far away, a[1000] etc. `cuda-memcheck` can detect the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accessing an array just slightly out-of-bounds generally will not result in an obvious runtime error (although your code may still compute things incorrectly).  The GPU runtime mechanisms do not test access validity down to the byte level.

If you make the access far enough out of bounds, you will eventually hit a runtime error.

The same statements are true in my experience for CPU host code as well (try it).

Because of this, on the CPU side you can use a tool like `valgrind` to catch such errors, and on the GPU side you can use a tool like `cuda-memcheck` to catch such errors.

Comment: Ah in my program it's not just slightly out-of-bounds, but 1-2 KB away out of bound (a[2000] for example). I'll run cuda-memcheck in addition to nvprof

Comment: cuda-memcheck found the error immediately. I guess cuda-memcheck checks the memory more careful than nvprof. Thanks!

Comment: There's no way to tell how far out of bounds you are from what you posted in your original question.   nevertheless the statements I made are correct: 1.  If you are far enough out of bounds, the runtime will eventually catch it.  2.  `cuda-memcheck` will catch it.  `nvprof` is not a debugging or correctness tool.  It is a performance profiler, and it should only be used when you know your code is not doing any illegal behavior.  It's good practice to make sure your code is fully correct before trying to use `nvprof`.  `cuda-memcheck` is a good tool choice to help with that.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I totally forgot about cuda-memcheck